# Showing a custom domain during sign in with firebase

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Users can sign in using Googleand my application is not hosted on firebase but on another hosting provider.

When signing in with Google, I want to display Sign in to `myapp` instead of `firebase-project-id.firebaseapp.com`. I checked this documentation: [https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/show-custom-domain#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20Identity%20Providers,instead%20of%20the%20default%20domain](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/show-custom-domain#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20Identity%20Providers,instead%20of%20the%20default%20domain). but it seems to assume that I am hosting my app on firebase.

Any suggestions how to do that?